# OpenSSL error - handshake failure

Tags: php, apache, api, ssl

On about every second request I make to an API I get this error!?

The backend on the API is one of my own servers which I have setup myself with self-signed SSL certs

What is happening here!? It can't be the SSL certs because it works in some cases

```
Warning:  fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in
```

## API request code

```
$Request = new Request();
$Request->host = $host;
$Request->api_secret = 'asdf39Sf3D';
$Request->send($url, $params);
echo $Request->get_result();

class Request {
    public $host;
    public $api_secret;

    public $boundary;
    public $body;

    private $response;
    private $url;

    const SSL = true;

    public function send($url, $post_vars=array()){
        $this->url = $url;

        $crlf = "\r\n";

        $host = $this->host;
        $port = 80;

        if(self::SSL){
            $host = 'ssl://'.$this->host;
            $port = 443;
        }

        if($this->body){
            $body = $this->body;
        }
        else{
            $post_vars['__api_hash'] = $this->generate_hash($this->url);
            $body = http_build_query($post_vars);
        }

        $content_length = strlen($body);

        $max_post = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
        if($content_length > $max_post){
            throw new Exception("Max post size exceeded");
        }

        if($fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 20)){
            fwrite($fp, 'POST '.substr($this->url, strlen($this->host)).' HTTP/1.1'.$crlf
                .'Host: '.$this->host.$crlf
                .($this->body ? 'Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$this->boundary : 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded').$crlf
                .'Content-Length: '.$content_length.$crlf
                .'Connection: Close'.$crlf.$crlf
                .$body);

            while($line = fgets($fp)){
                if($line !== false){
                    $this->response .= $line;
                }
            }

            fclose($fp);
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception("$errstr ($errno)");
        }
    }

    public function get_response(){
        return $this->response;
    }

    public function get_result(){
        list($header, $content) = explode("\n\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $this->response));

        preg_match('/^HTTP\/[\d\.]+ (\d+)/', $header, $matches);
        switch($matches[1]){
            case 404:
                throw new Exception('HTTP 404 '.$this->url);
        }

        return json_decode($content, true);
    }

    public function generate_hash(){
        return sha1($this->url.$this->api_secret);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am making an vaguely educated guess here... there was a well-publicized SSL/TLS [renegotiation issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer#Renegotiation_attack) in 2009. You are probably seeing the result of code added to protect against unsafe renegotiation. Can you try using TLS instead of SSL - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153206/how-to-make-tls-connection-from-php-in-web-server-and-safely

Comment: Have tried to use the `tls://` protocol instead, but still same error in about half of the requests and the second half responses without any problems.. hmmm

Comment: On the server you are connecting to, which version of OpenSSL is being used? If one side of the communication is patched to fix the _unsafe renegotiation_ issue then this might also cause the error you are seeing. Both sides need to have the patched version of SSL or both unpatched; well that was the case for me using Java client and server, although there were 2 flags that could be used in Java to override this if necessary. From the [OpenSSL changelog](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html), it looks like you need at least `v0.9.8m`

Comment: `phpinfo()` returns this `OpenSSL 0.9.8u 12 Mar 2012`
But can't check the installed version on Apache.. When running `openssl /?` in the prompt this error is returned `The ordinal 320 could not be located in the dynamic link library SSLEA32.dll`.. Wamp is installed on windows

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178815/wamp2-https-and-ssl you might have incompatible versions of OpenSSL on the client and server, or maybe the certificate is somehow incorrect. Is this just a single WAMP server running PHP that you use or is the host you are talking over SSL to a different server?

Comment: @andyb, create an answer :) after downloading the latest version of openSSL and replacing `libeay32.dll`, `openssl.exe` and `ssleay32.dll` in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin` it works !! :D

Comment: Good news! I'll create an anwser based on my comments. Incidentally, does it still work if you switch back to `ssl://`?

Comment: am only using ssl:// :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a well-publicized SSL/TLS [renegotiation issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer#Renegotiation_attack) in 2009. You are probably seeing the result of code added to protect against unsafe renegotiation. If one side of the communication is patched to fix the unsafe renegotiation issue then this might also cause the error you are seeing. Both sides need to have the patched version of SSL or both unpatched. From the [OpenSSL changelog](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html), it looks like you need at least `v0.9.8m`.

Looking at [Wamp2 and "The ordinal 942 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178815/wamp2-https-and-ssl) you possibly have a bad version of of OpenSSL that shipped with WAMP.

Comment: download the latest version of openSSL and replace `libeay32.dll`, `openssl.exe` and `ssleay32.dll` in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin`... then it works :D