# Making a connection in PHP using TLS

Tags: php, ssl

I wrote a small SIP client for a special purpose.
Basically it connects to port 5060 using function `fsockopen()`

```
$fp = fsockopen("10.0.0.1", 5060, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

and then basically reads and writes SIP commands using `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

Now my SIP service operator wants us clients to use SIPS which is 
basically SIP over TLS.  I've spent hours looking for information
on how to connect to a port with TLS using PHP but without any 
success.  Apparently the `fsockopen()` supports TLS to an extent but 
when I replaced the above with:

```
$fp = fsockopen("tls://10.0.0.1", 5061, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

I get nothing.  I can connect to the server from my shell with with OpenSSL client:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.1:5061
```

And I can communicate with the SIP server through that connection without problems. OpenSSL support is compiled in the PHP.

My problem is that I can't set up the TLS connection with the server in PHP. I noticed in some forums that in older versions of PHP it was possible to build and use the SSL context with `fsockopen()` but apparently not anymore, since I get an error about too many parameters.

I also tried using `stream_context_create()` with `stream_context_set_option()` but I get no replies from the server:

```
$context = stream_context_create();
$result=stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', 'TRUE');
$result=stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'cert.cer');
$result=stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_depth', '5');

$fp = stream_socket_client('tls://'.$host.':'.$port, $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

but I still can't get any replies or errors from the server. What is the recommended and working way of using TLS in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is enough to open a TLS connection:

```
$context = stream_context_create();

$fp = stream_socket_client('tls://'.$host.':'.$port, $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context)
```

if the certificates are in their place. If they are not, follow the instructions linked by Filippos.

Comment: Btw, if you are implementing a TLS (or SSL) connection in PHP, `stream_set_timeout` won't work (I'm running PHP 5.4.4 from the CLI). I ended up using `stream_select` as a work-around.

Comment: how to provide cert and password?

Answer (score 2):

I think some of your options are wrong for validating self signed certificates; the following should be enough to make it work:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
  'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'allow_self_signed' => true,
    'local_cert' => 'cert.cer',
  ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to install the appropriate certificates to get TLS working. [Check this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153206/how-to-make-tls-connection-from-php-in-web-server-and-safely) for an example of how to use your key files with regular TLS connections.

Also, check the specs of SIPS itself in [RFC 5630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5630).

Answer (score 0):

I just recently encountered this error, debugging here and there for connection problem or proxy problem, finally found the culprit ... and the solution was to install php-pecl-crypto extension.

My machine is centos 7 using remi-repo for PHP