# How to use TLS protocol on cURL?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, server

Actually the code:

```
$data = '{"params": ["testing_true", "bb4238e7-8f6d-4b2e-9ea4-43791bfb72df"], "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "gate.check", "id": 27034}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "tls://site.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 4928); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,      array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' .    strlen($data)                                                                       
));       

$output = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_error($ch));

var_dump(curl_errno($ch));

echo($output) . PHP_EOL;

curl_close($ch);
```

With this treatment I get

```
Protocol tls not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Here is an example of recourse to TLS, as it is to make friends with cURL? [How to make TLS connection from PHP in web server, and safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153206/how-to-make-tls-connection-from-php-in-web-server-and-safely/3153717#3153717)

Answer (score 0):

You want HTTPS:// which is the name for the protocol that is HTTP over TLS.

So, "https://example.com" etc.

Comment: But why here used namely TLS protocol? I need use TLS protocol also. http://clip2net.com/s/38ugHJa

Comment: That example isn't using curl!

Comment: Ok, how i can request my $data without cURL? Using json rpc & tls/ssl protocol?

Comment: That's a completely different question though. And one I'm not the suitable person to answer...